# Proof by induction for infinite unions/intersections

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, induction

Say I want to prove the following statement: The union of a countable collection of countable sets is countable.

Imagine I wrote a proof that went something like this: let $E$ be a collection of countable sets, that I can index $E=\{E_1, E_2,...\}$ with the natural numbers, and show for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\bigcup_{i<n}E_i$ is countable.

I understand that this is an invalid argument. The argument above only shows for all finite collections, as we never show $P(n) \implies P(\infty)$; that is, we never actually consider the entire collection of sets.

Now, consider a different problem. Say I want to prove the Nested Intervals Theorem([https://math.gmu.edu/~dsingman/315/sect1.6nounc.pdf](https://math.gmu.edu/%7Edsingman/315/sect1.6nounc.pdf)). The infinite intersection of sets is defined as $\bigcap^\infty E_i=\{ a: a\in E_i \hspace{.2cm}\forall i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I believe that an induction argument does work here. If I prove that there is some real number $a$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a \in \bigcap^n_1 E_i$, then I think that I prove $a \in \bigcap^\infty E_i$.

I think the above works because this argument: assume $a \not \in \bigcap^\infty E_i$, then $\{i \in \mathbb{N}: a \not \in E_i \} \not = \emptyset$. let $k$ be the least such element of this set. then, $a \not \in E_k$ but $a \in E_{k-1}$ which contradicts the proof by induction .

Of course I have searched through related post. I remain unsatisfied. The best answers on this post, for example, does not agree with me: [How is an induction 'proof ' of 'The principle of nested closed intervals' different that the standard proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262867/how-is-an-induction-proof-of-the-principle-of-nested-closed-intervals-diffe).

Are there any errors in my thinking?

Comment: By assuming your $a$ for each $n\ge 1$ lies in the finite intersection $E_1 \cap E_2 \cdots E_n,$ you have already assumed it lies in every $E_i.$ The original argument is to only assume each finite intersection is nonempty, not that it is the same $a$ making each finite intersection nonempty at once.

Comment: In the linked post at the bottom, someone writes:

Comment: $$\forall n: P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i)$$

for some predicate, $P$.

That is a different statement than:

$$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)$$

Answer (score 1):

The Nested Intervals Theorem applies to closed intervals of $\Bbb R.$ It follows from a basic property of $\Bbb R:$ If $\emptyset\ne S\subset \Bbb R$ and if $S$ has an upper bound in $\Bbb R$ then $lub(S)$ exists in $\Bbb R.$ This property (or a consequence of it) $must$ be used in a proof. For example if we replace $\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb Q$ it fails, e.g. if $E_i=\{q\in\Bbb Q:0<q\land |q^2-2|\le 1/i\}$ then there is no $a\in \Bbb Q$ such that $a\in\cap_{i\in\Bbb N}E_i.$

You have made a valid criticism of the attempt to prove by induction that a countable union of countable sets is countable. Induction does not require the Axiom of Choice (AC). Since Paul Cohen's breakthrough called Forcing (a difficult topic), it has been shown that if the rest of the axioms (ZF) of set theory are consistent, then ZF without AC cannot prove that every countable union of countable sets is countable.